# How to prevent JRE from running JAR's that are not signed?

Tags: java, java-21

I have to lock down the JRE as much as possible.
With the deprecation of Java Security Manager in Java 21, there is (to my knowledge) no way to lock down the JRE to run only a selected handful of standalone JAR's.

Am I missing something or is there no way to let JRE only run JAR's that are signed with a specific certifcate?

All documentation regarding this topic points to Java SE 8 and using Security Manager. The official documentation mention a Java Cryptography Extension Policy file but there is no further documentation about it.

Comment: Can you explain why you need "to lock down the JRE" in more detail? If you actually succeed in doing so, what is preventing me from using a JRE other than yours to run your application?

Comment: What does “lock down the JRE” even mean? The security manager was never responsible for a feature like “to let JRE only run JAR's that are signed with a specific certifcate”, even before its deprecation. As Thomas Behr said, you need to explain how your requested feature was supposed to work in the first place, e.g. in Java 8.

Comment: @ThomasBehr Locking down meaning only JAR's that are signed by a trusted CA should be allowed to run.
@ Holger I think I have mixed it up with Java Applets/JWS. There you can enforce the JARs to be signed by a specific certificate.
Nontheless is there any way to prevent JRE from running arbitrary JREs? Excluding the applications that bring their own.

Comment: I think that the answer is No ... unless you want to modify OpenJDK and make your own JRE builds.

Comment: @Torben My question was *why* you want to lock down the JRE, not what you mean by "locking" (you already explained that in your initial post). I am asking for your reasons, because I do not understand why you need to do that. If the JRE is on a machine which you do not control, you cannot prevent people from using a JRE other than your locked one. If the JRE is on a machine you do control, simply do not run applications you do not trust. In the first case, "locking" won't do any good, in the second case, there is no need for "locking" at all.

Comment: Well, Applets and JWS had a need for such a feature, as jar files were coming from external sources. JWS has been gone already, Applets have been marked *deprecated, for removal*, expect it to go together with the security manager. So what is the hypothetical feature for? In case of local launches, you are in control of the launch, you decide which jars to specify to the JVM. Or, to look at it from the other side, if you do not take control over the launch process, you don’t have control over the hypothetical signed-jars-only restriction either.

Comment: @Holger Well, any application can load jars from external sources (think plug-ins). So, this applet/webstart security issue is there for "normal" applications as well. However, an application that loads external, unsigned jars or simply fails to verify signatures for external jars should not be "trusted" in the first place. Unfortunately, it takes quite some effort to check if an application loads insecure stuff. Moreover, it is fairly easy for a malicious party to sign their evil plug-in which begs the question how secure a signed jar really is.

Comment: @ThomasBehr …and every application can download a binary file and run it. Or contain the problematic stuff already in the first place, without the need to download it.

Comment: @Holger Exactly. I think we're on the same page, here. ;)